# I need advice with making "Secret Friend" on java for Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arraylist

I'm trying to make this app for android, but here's the problem, I fill 2 lists, then I shuffle them, then I make a for to mix them and make the "couples", but before this I made a while to see if the final list(the list with the couples), is the same size as the original list (if this is true so everything is ok, since the couples will be the same size as the people playing), ALWAYS if the app goes to the while, it crashes, only if never goes to the while, I get the couples, here's my code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { //when the app starts
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_amigo__secreto);

        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        lista = new ArrayList<String>();
        AdminSQLiteOpenHelper admin = new AdminSQLiteOpenHelper(this, "amigoS", null, 1);

        this.llenarLista();
        this.llenarLista2();
        if (lista.size() > 1){ //if there are more than 2 people do this
            Collections.shuffle(lista);
        Collections.shuffle(lista2);
        reproductor = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.cancion);
        reproductor.setLooping(true);
        reproductor.start();
        sorteo(); //here is the problem, look
    }
    }

public int sorteo() {
        do {
            listaParejas.clear();
            listaSalidos.clear();
            int start2;
            for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
                start2 = random.nextInt(lista2.size() - 0) + 0;
                if (lista2.get(start2).equals(lista.get(i))) { if the person who receives is equals to the one who gives, continue
                    continue;
                } else { //here I add who gives and receives
                    listaParejas.add(lista.get(i) + "->" + lista2.get(start2));
                    listaSalidos.add(lista2.get(start2));
                    lista2.remove(start2); //And remove the person who receives so that he'll never get out again
                }
            }
        } while (listaParejas.size() != lista.size());
        return 0;
    }
```

Please any advice, I don't know what to do next, I've trying and trying, but I have no idea why always in the while, the app fails... Thanks

Comment: Your problem is not well explained and the question is not clear. Please try to improve it a bit

Comment: Ok I think I got it, you mean a "Secret Santa" app.

Answer (score 0):

I think your process is based on the luck of your random factor to make the process to finish. This is not ok at all, specially because you are doing it in the main thread. What I would do is:

1. Take the first list, make a copy and shuffle it using a random sort. See for example `Collections.shuffle(list)`.
2. Take the first list and make the couples using the following logic:

---

1. Take the first element of the first list and couple it with the first element of the second list.
2. If the element from the first list is the same as the element in the second, take the next one.
3. Remove the elements from both lists.
4. Repeat until the lists are empty.

This is also ensuring you have the same number of elements and that they are not the same. You can also use a queue or a stack to make your life easier.